# Unable to see Time and Data of InfluxDB in Grafana Graph

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a measurement called "testtable" where I have kept my testcaseIDs in 1 column, time in 1 column and latency which is a value in one column. I fetched latency from the influxDB query in Grafana.
[image]

I see the output in the table format. I am unable to see the data in the timeseries graph. Also, how do I consider the time data read from the influxdb as my x-axis and y-axis as Latency with the graph showing the data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latency is a string, e.g. `1.24s` - you can't graph strings in the Grafana. Only numbers e.g. `1.24` (integers/floats) can be graphed. Also InfluxDB doesn't have `column`, but it has `fields` and `tags`. Make sure your latency is a field.

Comment: I am unable to plot even after changing latency to numbers. And yes Latency is a field.

Comment: after selecting the proper time range from the Grafana time range dropdown, I am able to see the graph. Thank you.